# BMP Image Compression and Decompression in java

Tags: java, compression, javax.imageio, bmp

I am searching for a way to compress and decompress a BMP Image in java.

I found an easy way using javax.imageio , like the following [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_dip/image_compression_technique.htm)  .

using the following two classes ([ImageWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html) , [ImageWriteParam](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriteParam.html)) , but the example provided is just compressing an Image .

what i am looking for is use the same classes and the same mechanism to decompress "my compressed image" that i got from the provided example .

Is there anyway to do this with same mechanism ?

any other solution to compress a BMP are also welcome .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is `ImageIO.read(new File("my compressed image"))` what you are looking for? You can use `ImageIO`, and the `javax.imageio` API to read and write BMP in Java. Just replace the the format name with "BMP" and optionally remove the compression settings from what is used in the tutorial. But I guess I don't fully understand what you are asking here...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest ways to read and write images in Java using ImageIO, is just using the `read` and `write` static methods directly.

Read:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("input.bmp"));
```

Write:

```
BufferedImage image = ...; // from disk or created in memory, etc

if (!ImageIO.write(image, "BMP", new File("output.bmp"))) {
    // TODO: Handle not written case
}
```

Using the `ImageReader` and `ImageReadParam`, and `ImageWriter` and `ImageWriteParam` respectively (as in the tutorial), gives more control over what parts of the image to decode, size or region, or format features such as compression type, quality to encode etc., *if you need it*.